# Is there a way to check if one bit is set and another is not at the same time?

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation

Sorry this has probably been asked before but it's rather hard to search for.  I'm trying to figure if some bits have been set and some have not been set in a single operation. Is this possible?

e.g. I want to check if the fifth bit is off but either the second or third bit are on.

Comment: In any particular language? It wouldn't be a true "single operation", but you could one-line something this in many languages.

Comment: This is something I run into a lot writing SQL queries and wishing I didn't have to add an AND WHERE to check the second bitmask.

Comment: In SQL, it's generally better *not* to encode multiple facts into bitfields.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Agreed (and added that as a note in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SQL situation you suggested, you could just mask out the three bits and perform an `IN` check for the patterns you accept, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (field & 0x16) IN (0x2, 0x4);
```

or if you accept both second and third bits being set at once, you can just do a range check, since all three combinations you accept exhibit no overlap with the range of the not accepted options:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (field & 0x16) BETWEEN 0x2 AND 0x6;
```

I'll note that while this works, it's not great style for SQL (or any language really). In practice, you'd probably want to stick with named single `BIT` (`NOT NULL`) fields, which provides more information to SQL (potentially allowing indexed searches and the like). Writing

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (field2 = 1 OR field3 = 1) AND field5 = 0;

-- or for mutually exclusive
WHERE field2 + field3 = 1 AND field5 = 0;
```

is not meaningfully longer, and it's significantly more clear what you're doing (assuming you have more useful field names of course).